# Can't figure out how to create exchange rate tables

Tags: sqlite

These are two commands I try to execute to create a pair or tables related to exchange rates.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Currencies(
      numeric_code integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      code text NOT NULL UNIQUE

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ExchangeRates(
      id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      numeric_code integer NOT NULL,
      exchange_rate real NO NULL,
      date_from date NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (numeric_code) REFERENCES Currencies(numeric_code)
```

I get the error: `SQLITE_ERROR: incomplete input errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'`

What is wrong? I am not good at SQL queries.

Comment: Add `);` to each one of the two statements.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it